# En-/decode 3bit uints into compact format (e.g. byte slice)

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

Having a slice of `uint8` but knowing that the uints are all smaller than 8: is there a simple way to en-/decode into a compact type using 3 bits a uint?

Only thing I can come up with is a complicated way of building a byte slice.

Comment: Most likely not with the standard lib, but there are 3rd party libs, such as [`github.com/icza/bitio`](https://github.com/icza/bitio) (it's a bit-level Reader and Writer for Go; disclosure: I'm the author).

Comment: Assuming a bijective en-/decoding: No. Just write some code. (Other wise the problem becomes trivial).

Comment: Can you share an example to demonstrate your issue and your attempted solution so others can learn?